# Looping through Columns replicating each column fetched six times

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have this data frame where the column names are from v1 to v292. There are 17 observations. I need to iterate over the columns and replicate each column fetched 6 times.

For example:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4
1  3  4  6
3  4  3  1
```

What the output should be

```
x
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
1
3
3
4
3
4
3
4
3
4
3
4
3
4 .. and so on.
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rep`

```
data.frame(x = unlist(rep(df, each = 6)))
```

Checking output with `each = 2`

```
data.frame(x = unlist(rep(df, each = 2)))

#   x 
#1  1
#2  3
#3  1
#4  3
#5  3
#6  4
#7  3
#8  4
#9  4
#10 3
#11 4
#12 3
#13 6
#14 1
#15 6
#16 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. It helped a lot. Moreover slight tweaking the code served another output as well.